# Accessing a JSON in AngularJS using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<table class="table table-striped" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Zeroes</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-controller="ViewData as viewAll">
        <tr ng-repeat="pop in viewAll.number">
            <td>{{pop.number}}</td>
            <td>{{pop.zeroes}}</td>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have this table and I'm trying to get data to be outputted in it.

```
app.controller('ViewData', ['$http', '$scope',

    function($http,$scope) {

        $scope.viewAll = this;

        $http.get('/someurl').success(function(data) {

            $scope.viewAll.number = data;
        });
    }]);
```

This my controller getting the data.

```
 {"number": {
"4": {
    "zeroes": "5"
},
"5": {
    "zeroes": "6"
},
"10": {
    "zeroes": "7"
}}
```

And this is the data that /someurl is giving out to me.. Is there any way I can be able to handle this so I can be able to show it outside the table.
Thanks in advance for any kind of help given!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<table class="table table-striped" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Zeroes</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-controller="ViewData as viewAll">
        <tr ng-repeat="{key, value} in viewAll.number">
            <td>{{key}}</td>
            <td>{{value.zeroes}}</td>
    </tbody>
</table>

app.controller('ViewData', ['$http', '$scope',

    function($http,$scope) {

        var self = this;

        $http.get('/someurl').success(function(data) {

            self.number = data;
        });
    }]);
```